# I am unable to trucate my data with foreign key relation. After truncating the child data is truncated

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have the tables with foreign key relationship. I had already truncated the child table data, But after that also i am unable to delete parent table data. Why...? I had primary key constraint for that foreign key column.

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys
02266. 00000 -  "unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample tables & data:

```
SQL> create table tdept (deptno number constraint pkd primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table temp  (emp number primary key, deptno number constraint fkd
  2    references tdept (deptno));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into tdept values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into temp values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

This is what you did - truncated detail (child) table:

```
SQL> truncate table temp;

Table truncated.
```

Truncating master (parent) table doesn't work:

```
SQL> truncate table tdept;
truncate table tdept
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys
```

Therefore, disable foreign key constraint, truncate the master table and enable the FK:

```
SQL> alter table temp disable constraint fkd;

Table altered.

SQL> truncate table tdept;

Table truncated.

SQL> alter table temp enable constraint fkd;

Table altered.
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table <Table Name> disable constraint <constraint name>;
```

Disable constraint delete data and add constraint again.

Comment: I have tried it doesn't worked out. I am unable to disable the constraint because of it is primary key for the table.

Comment: Again, without error or table DDL, it difficult to guess .

Comment: error is like can't disable the primary constraint of an index or a table.

Comment: `select CONSTRAINT_NAME from  all_constraints where TABLE_NAME =<Your 
 table> and CONSTRAINT_TYPE ='R'`

Comment: @peridin Please disable above contraint not PK